# QTableview: How to add a blank row at the bottom and have it show delegates

Tags: pyqt, qtableview

Question: How do you insert a blank row at the bottom of the table and have delegates appear once the row is edited?

What I did so far: I have added a new row at the bottom of the QTableView by incrementing the row count, like so:

```
def rowCount(self, parent = None):
    return super(TransactionTblSqlQueryModel,self).rowCount() + 1
```

However when editing the last row the default delegates are not present. Only after saving/submitting and then editing this row does the delegates appear...

Comment: On rowchange. (I am sub-classing a QSqlQueryModel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get the default delegates to work but, you can create custom delegates and then set them to the desired columns of a QTableview

First create the delegates:

```
class LineEditDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, QWidget, QStyleOptionViewItem, QModelIndex):
        return QtWidgets.QLineEdit(QWidget)

    def setEditorData(self, QWidget, QModelIndex):
        try:
            value = QModelIndex.model().data(QModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            QWidget.setText(value)
        except:
            QWidget.setText("")

    def setModelData(self, QWidget, QAbstractItemModel, QModelIndex):
        try:
            value = QWidget.text()
            QAbstractItemModel.setData(QModelIndex, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        except:
            QAbstractItemModel.setData(QModelIndex, "", QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, QWidget, QStyleOptionViewItem, QModelIndex):
        QWidget.setGeometry(QStyleOptionViewItem.rect)


class SpinBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, QWidget, QStyleOptionViewItem, QModelIndex):
        return QtWidgets.QSpinBox(QWidget)

    def setEditorData(self, QWidget, QModelIndex):
        try:
            value = QModelIndex.model().data(QModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            QWidget.setValue(value)
        except:
            QWidget.setValue(0)

    def setModelData(self, QWidget, QAbstractItemModel, QModelIndex):
        try:
            value = QWidget.value()
            QAbstractItemModel.setData(QModelIndex, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        except:
            QAbstractItemModel.setData(QModelIndex, 0, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, QWidget, QStyleOptionViewItem, QModelIndex):
        QWidget.setGeometry(QStyleOptionViewItem.rect)
```

Then set the delegates to the QTableview's columns

```
class Controller(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        lineEditDelegate = LineEditDelegate(self.__ui.tableView)
        spinBoxDelegate = SpinBoxDelegate(self.__ui.tableView)
        self.__ui.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, lineEditDelegate)
        self.__ui.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(5, spinBoxDelegate)
        ...
```

The custom delegates should now appear as expected